# Date wise sorting of an oracle table without any date column

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table with a million rows in oracle. But it doesn't have any date column. Is it still possible that I can sort the rows based on the date they were created on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORA_ROWSCN` seems to be what you are looking for. Note that it has some conditions. See [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/583307?start=0&tstart=0) for details.

Comment: `ROWSCN` tracks the last change to the column, not the creation date.

Comment: That was what I meant with "conditions". If rows don't change, then the creation date is equal to the last update date.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The closest you can get is with [`ORA_ROWSCN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns007.htm), but unless you have row dependencies enabled that wll reflect changes at block level rather than row level, and if rows have been updated it will refer to that time not the original row insertion time.